# Why `std::unordered_set<std::vector<int>>` does not compile whereas `std::unordered_set<int>` is ok?

Tags: c++, stl

Here is the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/vsYr6sbzv).

Why `std::unordered_set<std::vector<int>>` does not compile whereas `std::unordered_set<int>` is ok?
Could someone please give me a detailed explanation?

**UPDATE**:
Here is the error messages:

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::unordered_set<_Value, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_set() [with _Value = std::vector<int>; _Hash = std::hash<std::vector<int> >; _Pred = std::equal_to<std::vector<int> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<int> >]'
    ...
```

Tips:  Sorry, I can't fully understand the error message.

```
  #include <vector>
  #include <algorithm> 
  #include <unordered_set>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>
  
  int main()
  {
    std::unordered_set<std::vector<int>> set_of_vector;  //Why this one goes wrong?

    std::unordered_set<int> set_of_int;

    return 0;                    
  }
```

Comment: What is the error message? Search for it online, too! What have you found as requirements for elements of unordered_set? See cppreference.com for example.

Comment: `unordered_set` is a hash table, which requires a hash function (hasher). C++ standard library does not provide hashers for containers. You can use the one from Boost. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/P8zh816aY

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt updated.

Comment: BTW: I searched for "[c++] unordered_set", simple as that.

Comment: @DanielLangr After I have carefully studied your demo code. It seems that I should **also** pass a suitable implementation of **equality comparison** as a third template parameter of std::unodered_set(i.e. something like `std::vector<int>, boost::hash<std::vector<int>>, boost::compare<std::vector<int>>` other than `std::vector<int>, boost::hash<std::vector<int>>>`). **Am I right**?

Comment: @John I am not 100% sure but I think the comparison operator for `std::vector` should be fine. What is the difference with `boost::compare`?

Comment: @Daniel Langr If I correctly understand you, since there is `operator==()` for `std::vector` in `std c++`, so **I don't have to provide one by myself**. Am I right?

Comment: @John Yes, there is. Have you checked the reference? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp

Comment: @Daniel Langr Thank you for your clarification. With your help, my understanding of this matter is at a different level. The reference is so hard for me to fully understand.